# SpriteKit score is acting randomly

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, game-physics

I am creating a game with SpriteKit and attempting to increase the score upon a collision. For some odd reason every time the score increase it is by a random number not just 1.

In the `didBeginContact` method I have a collision between a bullet and an alien. Every time the collide I would like the score to increase the score by 1. Except it has a mind of it's own and will randomly increase it by a number between 1 - 6. I have been through every line of code and have attempted to add scoring into the game multiple times but it just won't increase by 1 as I would like it too. At the moment my code is like this.

In my header file I create a property for the score:

```
@property (nonatomic) int score;
```

Then in my main game scene, I add the following

```
-(void)setScore:(int)score
{
    _score = score;
    _scoreLabel.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", score];
}
```

In my init method I also set the score to start at 0

```
self.score = 0;
```

In my new game method I also make sure the score is set back to 0

```
self.score = 0;
```

Then my collision detection looks like this. I increment the score with self.score++;

```
if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == kAlienCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == kBulletCategory) {
        //Collision Between Bullet & Alien
        self.score++;
        if (firstBody.node) {
            [self alienExplosion:firstBody.node.position];
            [firstBody.node removeFromParent];
        }
        if (secondBody.node) {
            [self bulletExplosion:secondBody.node.position];
            [secondBody.node removeFromParent];
        }
    }
```

UPDATE: I added an NSLog to show how the score was updating in the console. And it showed exactly how the score was updating randomly between 1 - 6. The screenshot of the console shows the score updating to 6 where it should only have been 1

[image]

[image]

Comment: I would suggest putting in a breakpoint just before/after the score is being updated to get a sense of where things might be going awry

Comment: Do you mean where the score is increased in the collision detection?

Comment: I have spent the last few hours trying to figure it and still, can't fix it. I put breakpoints at every section the score was updating and it was all fine just incrementing by 1. So the problem still persisted, with the score updating between 1 - 6. So I put a NSLog statement to display the score in the console and it showed exactly the problem. The score will update with either a number between 1 - 6. I have put a screenshot in the question for reference

Comment: So, your code gets executed 6 times instead of 1? Did you check if the same collision gets called multiple times (if that's even possible) Try to set up a BOOL property to check if nodes have already started exploding.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Box2D (the physics engine that SpriteKit uses internally) a single contact can produce multiple invocations of the related callback function.

So your score value is being incremented several times because your method **didBeginContact** is called multiple times for the same contact.

You can prevent this behavior in several ways.
E.g. if your Alien can be hit by the bullet only once, you can **add a BOOL property isAlive to Alien** and change your code as follow.

```
//Collision Between Bullet & Alien
if (firstBody.categoryBitMask == kAlienCategory && secondBody.categoryBitMask == kBulletCategory) {
    Alien * alien = nil;
    if ([firstBody.node isKindOfClass:Alien.class]) {
        alien = (Alien*)firstBody.node 
    } else if ([secondBody.node isKindOfClass:Alien.class]) {
        alien = (Alien*)secondBody.node 
    }

    if (alien && alien.isAlive) {
        alien.isAlive = NO
        self.score++;
        if (firstBody.node) {
            [self alienExplosion:firstBody.node.position];
            [firstBody.node removeFromParent];
        }
        if (secondBody.node) {
            [self bulletExplosion:secondBody.node.position];
            [secondBody.node removeFromParent];
        }
    }
}
```