# Two sprites with same categoryBitMask colliding with third sprite

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, collision-detection

This is the code I'm using:

```
    func didBeginContact(contact: SKPhysicsContact) {

    var firstBody  : SKPhysicsBody?
    var secondBody : SKPhysicsBody?
    var thirdBody  : SKPhysicsBody?
    var GoodKind   : SKNode?
    var BadKind    : SKNode?
    var Bullet     : SKNode?

    if (contact.bodyA.categoryBitMask < contact.bodyB.categoryBitMask) {
        firstBody  = contact.bodyA
        secondBody = contact.bodyB

        GoodKind   = contact.bodyB.node
        BadKind    = contact.bodyB.node
        Bullet     = contact.bodyA.node
    }
    else {
        firstBody  = contact.bodyB
        secondBody = contact.bodyA

        GoodKind   = contact.bodyA.node
        BadKind    = contact.bodyA.node
        Bullet     = contact.bodyB.node
    }

    if (firstBody!.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Tooth && secondBody!.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Food) {
        GoodKind?.removeFromParent()
        Counter++
        println("\(Counter)")
    }
    else if (firstBody!.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.Tooth && secondBody!.categoryBitMask == PhysicsCategory.WrongFood) {
        BadKind?.removeFromParent()
        Bullet?.removeFromParent()
    }
}
```

If the `Bullet` collide with the `BadKind` then the `BadKind` is removed with the bullet which is fine; if the `Bullet` collide with the `GoodKind` then the `GoodKind` is removed and the `Counter` works fine, but if two or more `Bullet` collide with the `GoodKind` nearly at the same moment the `Counter` will increase 2 or more times. That is what I don't want to happen but I can't figure out how to make it work the way I want. I would appreciate some help.

Comment: You can try like this : http://stackoverflow.com/q/27883898/3402095

Comment: That wasn't quite what I needed

Comment: I solved thanks to this post http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27956637/didbegincontact-is-being-called-multiple-times-for-the-same-skphysicsbody